# Downloading a Nuget package is giving the error "Package contains an entry which is unsafe for extraction" why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

We are running a private nuget repository. Our build server creates nuget packages from a couple of our framework projects and copy these packages into the repository.
As of today we are receiving a weird error from nuget when we try to restore some packages.

`The package '[package name here]' contains an entry which is unsafe for extraction.`

Unfortunately I didn't find anything in google that was able to assist me.

My question is: What in a nuget package is considered being unsafe for extraction? Is there a list of entries, that must not be part of a package?

The package of the current version looks like the package of the previous versions, which still can be retrieved via the nuget manager.
Or is this something that came along with the latest visual studio patch for 15.8.2?

** *** UPDATE *** **
In the meanwhile we found out, that the problem appears in package manager `4.8.0.5385`. In versions `4.7.*` everything is working as expected. On [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) the latest *recommended* version of nuget.exe is 4.7.1! Unfortunately one doesn't have the option to opt out from updating the version, because it installed with the latest Visual Studio Patch for 15.8.2

Comment: Where does the error message come from? Output window on Visual Studio or  command prompt? I have never seen this error message from nuget. Have you tried re-create that package to test this issue again or temporarily turn off anti-virus software or firewall.

Comment: In Visual Studio (Output or in the nuget manager for solutions/project). We kinda narrowed it down the version of the package manager which is `4.8.0.5385`. Previous versions don't seem to be affected

Comment: Sounds like an issue on the package signing. Do you include a checksum on your packages? Are these correct? Looks like Nuget upped their package signing protocols earlier this year https://blog.nuget.org/20180810/Introducing-Repository-Signatures.html

Comment: Very good point. I'll have a look. Although I am wondering, if this is the case, I am wondering why this is working with the package manager version 4.7.! The link is saying that the verification started as of version 4.7. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer, If the error come from Visual Studio, it may be that the new version of NuGet adds some rules to detect our packages. Since I could not reproduce this issue, I could not confirm it. You could check if the contents of the package have some special files, if yes, try to remove or re-edit it.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [NuGet source code](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/3803820961f4d61c06d07b179dab1d0439ec0d91/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Packaging/PackageReaderBase.cs#L544L556), it looks like this occurs to prevent a ZIP traversal attack (sometimes called 'zip-slip')

Either your NuGet package contains a file that has a name that would cause it to be extracted in a bad location, or there is a bug in the NuGet client's way of determining that. If it's the latter, you would likely need to [file a bug](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/) to get it fixed.

Comment: As we don't sign our packages (yet), I guess this might be the problem. I don't find any files, that would be installed in a bad location. However, there is an empty folder named `.` in the package file. Maybe this is the problem. I'llt test and let you know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just had this problem, and found that there was a temp file (`exampl~1.txt`) which somehow sneaked in and caused the error. Removing the file fixed the error. I also came across [an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/1968) which alludes to the tilde (`~`) causing problems.

Comment: I worked around this by clearing the global package cache `nuget locals all -Clear`. Apparently the package cache folder was named `MyPackage` instead of `mypackage` and the code @vcsjones referenced seems to throw at this mismatch, even if Windows wouldn't really care.